# Unable resolve dependency after vue upgrade

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I try to upgrade my vue version from 3.0.2 to latest version with syntax:

```
vue upgrade
```

after that, my vue @vue/cli-service is upgraded to 5.0.8

But then when the process is want to upgade @vue/cli-plugin-babel and @vue/cli-plugin-eslint it say an error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: app-backend-vue@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@6.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^6.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">=7.5.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My devDependencies in `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  },
```

How to fix this? And how to clearly upgrade my vue version?

---

Before the upgrade, my devDependencies were

```json
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"eslint": "^6.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
```

Comment: Hi, did you tried the `--legacy-peer-deps` part?

Comment: I have try to ```npm install --legacy-peer-deps``` and its normal. But the cli-plugin-babel and cli-plugin-eslint not updated. When i run ```npm install```, its still conflict @kissu

Comment: Try to upgrade everything to their latest version (especially if doing a huge leap).

Comment: before i do vue upgrade, my devDependencies version:
```

    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
```

Comment: The current versions you do have are not the latest. Not sure what is the equivalent to `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest` in NPM but that would be a nice one to use.